# <br /> does not remove blank line?

Tags: html

I'm confused. I read the post answers related to my post and also tested on JSfiddle. It looked good on JSfiddle but not my page. I have 3 web pages for one site. I want to remove the blank line between the Job Position and the unordered list. This code did not work.

```
<div id="content">
        <h2><b>Experience</b></h2>
            <p><b>Job Position (ABC International: nn/nnnn-nn/nnnn))<br /></b>
            <ul>
                <li>Build </li>
                <li> Analyze </li>
                <li>Manage </li>
            </ul>
            </p>
            </div><!--/#content-->

/* Content Home Page
---------------------------------*/
#content {
    position: absolute;    
         top: 193px;   
        left: 15px;
     font-size: 15px;    
    float: right; 
    width: 50%;         
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Do I have to create another "div" for this? I thought `<br />` would remove the blank line.
Thank U

Comment: Oh, this should be I thought <br /> would remove the blank line. Thank U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank line is due to the default margin on paragraphs and lists.
Use this CSS:

```
p, ul {margin:0;}
```

You can get rid of the `<br />` tag as well.

Answer (score 4):

`<br />` will add a line break, it will not remove blanks lines. Remove the `<br />`.

Comment: Nope. Blank line is still there. Thank u

Comment: Can you post any CSS related to the `<ul>` or `<li>` tags please.

Comment: I have the Content Home Page CSS in the original post above. Let me know if you need something else. Thank u